# Who is Alice referring to when she was talking to Kate?

Tags: plot-explanation, arrowverse, batwoman

In an episode *of Batwoman*, after Alice is captured and locked up in a van, Kate goes to her to reassure her that she didn't lead the Crows. Alice responds by reciting something from Alice in Wonderland about 3 sisters before saying that she didn't like to share.

To me, this seems to like Alice is implying that Kate has a third sister. Who or what is she referring to?

Comment: I didn't see the episode yet, but if your hypothesis is correct and it is a mystery the series will likely explore, this falls into *future work* policy. I am not voting to close though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe the quote you are referencing is:

> "Tell us a story," said the March Hare.
>
> "Yes, please do," pled Alice, and so the Dormouse began "Once upon a time, there were 3 little sisters.

That being the case, Alice/Beth is Kate's sister but Mary Hamilton (played by Nicole Kang) is their **step**-sister being the daughter of Jacob Kane's second wife, Catherine.

[image]